# Issue a certificate in a different account than the domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager, amazon-certificate-manager

I have an account A where a domain is hosted, and A is the owner of that domain. I have another account B where I would like to issue a certificate in the subdomain of account A.    Any guidance on how to achieve this?

Account A Domain - [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
Account B - [www.accountb.example.com](http://www.accountb.example.com)

Answer (score 1):

Basically whenever we request ACM certificate it will ask to validate the domain. You can do it using DNS validation and Email validation.

Below link explain if you don't have route53 domain. You can basically manually add the DNS entries to the account A route 53 domain configuration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html